# What does ancestor mean in the google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

Can anyone tell or define more what is "ancestor" and give an example on it and also what it is for? I just can't grasp what it really is.

Reference: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_ancestor

Thanks.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding ancestor queries myself, so I made this post with some example code to shed some light on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532319/google-app-engine-datastore-nosql-example-with-ancestor-queries

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) in GAE only exist within ancestor-descendant groups.  Equivalently, quoting the docs at the URL I just gave,

> All datastore operations in a
>   transaction must operate on entities
>   in the same entity group

and an "entity group", per [this page in the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html), are defined by:

> When the application creates an
>   entity, it can assign another entity
>   as the parent of the new entity, using
>   the parent argument in the Model
>   constructor. Assigning a parent to a
>   new entity puts the new entity in the
>   same entity group as the parent
>   entity.

"Ancestor" is just the transitive closure of "parent" -- i.e., given an entity, its ancestors are, its parent, its parent's parent, and so forth.