# Do the unused properties consume size in gae datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, entities

In my design I have to store a lot of properties(say a 20 properties) in a same datastore table.
But usually most of the entities will occupy a minimum of only 5 properties.

Is this design a resource consuming idea? Will the unused properties consume any memory or performance?

Thanks,
Karthick.

Comment: yes, the names of the properties are stored = storage space for the names * number of records.

Comment: you can give the models a "long" name which is used when viewing the models etc and a short name which is actually saved in the datastore. If you have many model instances this may be useful. DOn't have a reference to hand atm

Comment: Hi Paul,
Instead of having many properties in the same entity, I am now creating many entities for the same user. A user can have 0 or n roles. I edit the username(it is the key) for every entity(an entity for a role for every student) by adding a code to it like studentname_captain, studentname_star, studentname_constructor etc. Every role will have the same parameters. So when a student wants to view his details, The system queries the table by adding '_captain', '_star' etc to the username and find the details by getObjectById.

Do you think this technique creates anyother issues in future?

Comment: My another doubt is, if we search with getObjectById and the key is not there, will it be counted as 1 read?

Thanks,
Karthick.

Comment: have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490261/what-does-ancestor-mean-in-the-google-app-engine-datastore and on last, look @ appstats https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are envisioning a system where you have: A Kind in your Datastore where the Entities for that Kind can have differing subsets of a common property-key space `W`. Entity 1's property set might be `{W[0], W[1]}`, and Entity 2's property set might be `{W[1], W[2], W[5]}`. You want to know whether this polymorphism (or "schemalessness") will cost you space, and whether each Entity, as in some naive MySQL implementations

The short answer is no - due to the schemaless nature of Datastore, having polymorphic entities in a kind (the entities have all different names and combinations of properties) will not consume extra space. The only way to have these "unused" properties consume extra space is if you actually did set them on the entity but set them to "null". If you are using the low-level API, you are manually adding the properties to the entity before saving it. Think of these as properties on a JSON object. If they aren't there, they aren't there.

In MySQL, having a table with many NULL-able columns can be a bad idea, depending on the engine, indexes, etc... but [take a look at this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) if you want to learn more about how the Datastore actually stores it's data using BigTable. It's a different storage implementation underneath, and so there are different best practices or possibilities.